# Как сделать грамотно индивидуальную настройку телеграм бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Есть телеграм бот и пользователь может менять настройки, к примеру ему будут приходить уведомления каждое n время, которое он себе установит.
Уведомления работают в отдельном файле и запускаются отдельно от основного бота, но привязаны к нему, чтобы понятнее объяснить: есть грубо говоря два файла, один основной бот, где можно менять настройки и там присутствуют остальные команды, и второй файл, где только бот с уведомлениями и это все работает через одного физического бота в телеграм

Вопрос заключается в том, как сделать так, чтобы пользователи могли индивидуально настраивать под себя алгоритм?
Есть идея после каждой настройки запускать отдельный поток со второй программой, но при этом с настройками конкретного пользователя, но если думать логически, то получается какая-то муть, есть ли решения более удобные?

Comment: Делал для бота сохранение в базе. Модель настроек https://github.com/gil9red/telegram__random_bashim_bot/blob/40914d79c7a735aa6f2bc078028f7ef1015d877c/bot/db.py#L127 В модели юзера добавил поле настроек https://github.com/gil9red/telegram__random_bashim_bot/blob/40914d79c7a735aa6f2bc078028f7ef1015d877c/bot/db.py#L160 В обработчике бота добавил команды для работы с настройками: https://github.com/gil9red/telegram__random_bashim_bot/blob/40914d79c7a735aa6f2bc078028f7ef1015d877c/bot/commands.py#L300-L422 В боте: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZB92.png и https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9N6m.png

Answer (score 0):

Использовать базу данных для хранения настроек пользователя, а потом по id их ему выдавать

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]